# js upload file - No files were uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am uploading  an image file on server-side and my script give an error

> error: "No files were uploaded."

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input name="file" type="file"/>
  <input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

JS code

```
$(':button').click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData($('form'));
    $.ajax({
        url: "/files/create",
        type: 'POST',
        success: completeHandler,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    });
    console.log(formData);
});

function completeHandler() {
    console.log("complete success");
}
```

Have anyone an idea? With what it can be connected?

Comment: can you include the output of `$_FILES` to see if the file have been posted or not.

Comment: why are you using js when you are using form? you can easily upload the file using form

Comment: @DileepKumar , sure - array(0) {} No Properties

Comment: @Exprator how? More specifically

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: @DileepKumar oh thanks

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `$('form')[0]` when you pass it to `FormData()`, to actually get the HTML-form element instead of the jQuery element?

Comment: i said only form and not ajax @MagnusEriksson, please see the comment properly

Comment: @Exprator I missed that the OP didn't have `even.preventDefault();`, which changes the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//HTML Part

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="file" type="file"/>
    <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>

//Js part
<script>
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
       url: '/files/create',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
       }
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
```

php part in your `create.php`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
      print_r($_FILES);
    }
?>
```